# Powershell takes too long to close; can't totally override the default prompt function

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I don't know what's happening with my Powershell. I have a shell registry key that allows me to open a Powershell window in a directory. The content is:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit
```

And this is my custom defined prompt function:

```
function prompt {
    Write-Host ("on ") -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host ("$env:COMPUTERNAME") -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Gray
    Write-Host (" in ") -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host ($(Get-Location)) -ForegroundColor Gray
    Write-Host ("$") -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Magenta

    return "> ";
}
```

It should return something like

> on PC-NAME in C:\
>
> $>

However, it returns this:

> on PC-NAME in C:\
>
> $> PS C:>

Anything wrong at all with my Powershell? How do I get more debug information to help you guys?

Comment: I have PowerShell 4.0 and I cannot replicate your issue. For me it works as you expect. try using the `-NoProfile` switch in case you have something in there.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue by commenting out a few functions in the PSReadline module that was installed. The module would add a `b to the end of the current prompt, append the user prompt to it, and would restore the default prompt when Powershell was being closed.